# Qt Creator 2.8.1 doesn’t see samsung galaxy s4 on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: android, c++, qt, ubuntu

Please, help with the following.
I'm trying to run example app with Qt 5.1.1 & Qt Creator 2.8.1 OS: (Ubuntu 13.10) on my Samsung galaxy s4 with Android 4.3.
But get error from Qt Creator: "cannot deploy:no device or emulator found for your package".
I tried using an emulator directly running it from SDK manager too, but got the same error.

adb sees devices:
"4d00050f7aa540c3 device  // - samsung s4
emulator-5554   device"

I activated usb debugging on the telephone through developer options.
I also added udev rule and now when device's plugged in, file with mode 0777 is created in /dev/bus/usb. In file manager i can see the telephone and can enter its storages. I also get request to accept RSA key and click OK.

Project settings:
- API level 14 (also tried latest versions);
- gcc 4.6 (android for armv7);

If I missed some info, please ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky to solve question: i'm using 64-bit version of Ubuntu, and installed appropriate android SDK Tools. But when i began to update it with "android" command line tool, it downloaded 32-bit versions of build-tools and platform-tools.

Therefore i added 32-bit architecture:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Then i got some errors from ant and downgraded build-tools from 19.0 to 18.1.1 with "android" cmd tool.

And it works!